Arzela-Ascoli lemma for separable (not necessarily compact) space: Can the subsequence converge to non-continuous function?
In Royden's Real Analysis there is an Arzela-Ascoli Lemma for separable space (which does not need compactness):

$X$ is a separable metric space and $(f_n)$ is an equicontinuous sequence of real valued functions in $C(X)$.
If $(f_n)$ is pointwise bounded (i,e. $\sup_{n\ge 1} |f_n(x)|<+\infty$ for all $x\in X$),
then exists a subsequence of $f_n$ that pointwise converges to some $f: X\in\mathbb R$.

My question is, since the theorem did not say if $f$ is continuous, is it possible to choose a subsequence of $f_n$,
subject to it pointwise converges to a non-continuous $f$?
By passing to the converging subsequence of $f_n$, it suffices to determine:

$X$ is a separable metric space.
$(f_n)$ is an equicontinuous sequence of real valued functions in $C(X)$ and $\lim_{n\to+\infty} f_n(x)$ exists for every $x\in X$.
Is $f(x)\overset{\text{def}}{=} \lim_{n\to+\infty} f_n(x)$ necessarily continuous?

(Pointwise boundness is implied by existence of pointwise limit).
The Arzela-Ascoli Theorem says $f$ is always continuous for compact $X$.
I have thought if counterexample lies in $X=[0,1)$ or $X=\mathbb R$.
But neither can work. (For $[0,1)$ a uniform continuous function extends to $1$ and $\mathbb R$ is union of compact set $[-n,n]$)

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equicontinuity: In particular, the limit of an equicontinuous pointwise convergent sequence of continuous functions $f_n$ on either metric space or locally compact space is continuous.

Thanks! I sticked to finding counterexamples. After I knew it is true, I found proving it quite easy. I have posted an answer.

Such $f$ must be continuous. The proof is as follows:
Given $\epsilon>0$ and $x_0\in X$, by equicontinuity, select $\delta>0$ subject to
if $d(x_0,x)<\delta$ then $|f_n(x)-f_n(x_0)|<\epsilon$ for all $n$.
For each $x\in X$ with $d(x_0,x)<\delta$, select index $n$ to let $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$ and $|f_n(x_0)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon$.
Then $$ |f(x_0)-f(x)|\le |f(x_0)-f_n(x_0)|+|f_n(x_0)-f_n(x)|+|f_n(x)-f(x)|<3\epsilon.  $$


If an equicontinuous sequence  $(f_n)$ of functions, from a topological space $X$ to a metric space $Y$, converges pointwise, then the limit $f$ is continuous.

Proof. Given $\epsilon>0$ and $x_0\in X$:

by equicontinuity, there exists a neighborhood $V$ of $x_0$ such that $d(f_n(x),f_n(x_0))<\epsilon$ for every $x\in V$;
by pointwise convergence, for every $x\in V$, $d(f(x),f(x_0))\le\epsilon$.

More generally, the closure in $Y^X$, equipped with the product topology, of any equicontinuous subset, is still equicontinuous.
